# Where can I normal temperature ranges for Intel processors

Tags: temperature

Where can I find the normal temperature ranges for Intel core i5 processors.

1. 1st generation?
2. 2nd generation?
3. 3rd generation?

Thanks.

Comment: All this information is present on the given product's page on the Intel website.

Answer (score 3):

Those information is available on http://ark.intel.com/

Select a processor and look at it's T_Case temperature value.

T_Case: "*To allow optimal system operation and long-term reliability, the processor must not exceed the maximum case temperature specifications as defined by the applicable thermal profile.*"

http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-033342.htm